# How to easily prove $x+\frac{1}{x} \ge 2 \quad ∀x\in ℝ^+$

Tags: inequality, problem-solving

When I tried to solve some certain math problem (an inequation) for pivate exercise purposes, I had to prove that  $x+\frac{1}{x} \ge 2 \quad ∀x\in ℝ^+$, I solved it with tools from differential calculus (prooving that there is a local minimum at $(1,2)$ etc), because this was my only concept.
But I guess one can prove this in a much simpler way, but I strangely do not get it — So: How can one prove this the most effective way?

Comment: Correct, I am sorry…

Comment: AM-GM: $\frac{x+\frac{1}{x}}{2}\ge\sqrt{x\cdot\frac{1}{x}}$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint**

Deduce the desired inequality from
$$(x-1)^2\ge0$$

Comment: Seconds apart. :) +1!

Comment: Aaaahhhh, I knew the answer would be too simple ;)
Must wait a few minutes to accept, though :)

Answer (score 3):

Hint: since $x$ is positive, multiply both sides by $x$. Then subtract $2x$ from both sides. Now factor to find... and now just reverse your steps :)

Answer (score 3):

$$x+ \frac{1}{x} \geq 2 \iff x^2+1 \geq 2x \iff x^2-2x+1 \geq \iff (x-1)^2 \geq 0$$

$$\text{The latter is true since $z^2=0 \iff z=0$} $$.

Answer (score 2):

$$0 \leq \left(\sqrt{x}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\right)^2$$